# Can a device have two UMDF Drivers?

Tags: python, driver, arduino, maya, umdf

This may seem like a bit of an odd question, but I was wondering if it is possible to associate two drivers with a peripheral device?

The reason I ask is that I am building an input device for [Maya](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autodesk_Maya) using an Arduino microcontroller. The Arduino already has its own device driver, but I was thinking of developing a [UMDF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_User_Mode_Driver_Framework) driver to take the data that comes in from Arduino over the serial port and pre-process it ready to go into Maya.

Right now, I have two Python programs running - a 32-bit Python program running outside of Maya which listens to the serial port and converts the data to a form which a second 64-bit program inside the 64-bit version of Maya can understand and use in the Maya scene. This works fine, but it is a bit annoying having to start that external server program every time I want to use this device in Maya. If I can have a UMDF driver ready to jump into action when the appropriate type of data comes in off the Arduino then this would help immensely. Will this approach work?

Comment: It's quite common for USB devices.

Answer (score 2):

It's more a comment/suggestion than an answer, but maybe it would be worth to invest some time and check if the filter driver would do the job for you. In [WDM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Driver_Model) you can put it above the kernel device driver on the driver stack for that device, and use it to pre-process your device data. I think it is also possible in UMDF.

See *[Creating a New Filter Driver (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh454832%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)*.

Comment: broken link? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/develop/creating-a-new-filter-driver

Answer (score 1):

You may always try to use [Teensy/Teensyduino](http://www.pjrc.com/teensy/) instead of Arduino to implement a virtual keyboard, mouse, joystick or other HID device. This does not require Windows drivers, and accessing the keyboard or joystick from Maya may be easier that the serial port.